# Will Internet Explorer 8, running on Windows XP after April 8, 2014, still get updates?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

I know that Windows XP itself won't get any more updates after April 8 (unless you've paid for them). But if I'm running IE8 on Windows XP after April 8, will I still be able to download IE8 updates?

I know it's not a good idea to keep running Windows XP after support ends, but much of the world will be doing just that, and I want to know what to tell people when they ask about this. I've checked Microsoft's Lifecycle information, and found nothing definitive. In fact, when you start looking at the lifecycle info on Internet Explorer, it gets rather circular.

References:

- http://support.microsoft.com/gp/LifeWinFAQ
- http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&qid=&alpha=Windows+Internet+Explorer+8&Filter=FilterNO

*Updated question to correct errors.*

Comment: IE 7 itself has not been supported for awhile now.  If you want updates you would need to install IE8.

Comment: I know it is not your question, but why keep IE7+ ? You are totally missing the web: you do not see it as it should be. And it's slow.

Comment: @Ramhound: can you point me to something from Microsoft that confirms this?

Comment: @vinz243: Okay, I'll change the question to IE8, or whatever the latest version is that XP can run.

Comment: Just why IE ? There is chrome, firefix, opera, max athon, lunarscape... IE 8 and 9 are also deprecated (as a web designer, I know that)

Comment: I know, why use IE at all, right? But the point is that people do use it, and I'd like to know what to tell them. If it turns out that IE7 can't be updated on XP, I'll be telling people still running XP that they absolutely MUST switch to something other than IE.

Comment: "Support ends 24 months after the next service pack releases or at the end of the product's support lifecycle, whichever comes first." This is what the [Lifecycle Information for Microsoft Additional Products Support](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifeadditionalproducts) page says about IE 7 on Windows XP SP3.  Either way, any browser would run in a potentially unsafe environment due to end of security updates. One could mitigate the problem by updating to IE 8 and switching to a third party browser, which would eventually stop supporting Windows XP, sooner or later.

Comment: @and31415: you're right, of course. I updated the question to be more specifically about IE8 instead of IE7. My bad. I also get your other point, but again, people are going to be doing this and I want to know what to tell them.

Comment: IE8 that exists on Windows XP will not be patched after the support for Windows XP ends in April.  **"Releases known as Components follow the Support Lifecycle of their parent Major Product."** is pretty clearl in this regard.

Comment: @Ramhound: The confusing part (for me, anyway) is whether they're talking about the version of IE *shipped* with a particular version of Windows, or *any* version of IE installed on that version of Windows. From what you're saying, they mean any version of IE. Elsewhere, Microsoft goes into a lot of detail regarding exactly which version of IE shipped with which version of Windows, including with service packs.

Comment: @boot13 See my previous comment. Even if Microsoft doesn't explicitly talk about IE 8 on Windows XP, the logical conclusion is that probably isn't any different than IE 7.

Comment: @and31415: You're probably right. But it would be useful if Microsoft made this more clear. Even your own comment leaves some room for doubt. I mean 'logical conclusion' sounds definitive enough, but you followed that up with 'probably'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [support matrix for IE](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=internet%20explorer) shows that all versions of IE are considered components of the operating system they are currently on. So when support for that OS ends, then support for any underlying components will also end (i.e. IE :-) ).

Practically speaking, IE 8 code was frozen feature-wise pretty much the day it was released, with the exception of security patches. If there were changes in HTML, like HTML5, only upgrading to the latest browser that implemented those features (like Canvas, WebSockets, etc) was the only way to expect to get those features.  If someone figures out a new way to hack into your pc thru a web page that involves a browser flaw, your XP IE8 system will not be getting updates to protected from that, but your Windows 7 IE8 would. The [Windows XP countdown and details page is here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/endofsupport.aspx)

One ambiguous statement on the Microsoft support matrix is the statement: "Releases known as Components follow the Support Lifecycle of their parent Major Product." Some people note that a version of IE 8 was introduced as part of Windows 7, and optionally upgraded in XP - and thus one could claim that IE 8 should be supported as long as Windows 7 is supported. However, [Microsoft supported pages like this one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/lifecycle-internet-explorer-8/2d64f20f-7801-4636-82be-456302181b37?msgId=884a824f-f61a-4d13-992a-5933e3acb58f) suggest that (components) "follow the support lifecycle of the OS on which they are running".

Comment: The Internet Explorer 8 bundled with Windows 7 is actually a different (albeit similar) program, and is referred to as "Windows Internet Explorer 8" by Microsoft.

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this answer, but I still have lingering doubts. The support matrix for IE doesn't actually state that "all versions of IE are considered components of the operating system they are currently on". In fact all it has is that one ambiguous statement you already pointed out. On the other hand, the support page you linked to seems to answer that question definitively. I just wish Microsoft would update the IE support matrix to be more clear on this point. The other confusing issue is the notion that IE8 on Windows XP is somehow not the same as IE8 on Windows 7.